# Conditional meta tag works on linux (Firefox) - it shouldn't

Tags: linux, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

My page don't support IE 9 or bellow, so I add conditional comment in index.php file:

```
<title>
        Title
    </title>
    <!--[if lte IE 9]>
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=Includes/min_browser.php" />
        <![endif]-->
    <?php
```

In min_browser.php I log on server $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']. The strange thing is that I get a lot of this user agents:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20150101 Firefox/44.0 (Chrome)"
```

Is this normal? I though that conditional comments are processed only by IE?
If yes, is javascript the only solution to achieve redirect to different page in case of IE < 10?